# How to keep this button open once it's been clicked

Tags: html, css

I'm currently creating a navigation menu and I want my sub sections such as "typography" to stay open in the menu once they have been clicked and the new page has been loaded.

How would I best best to complete this task

Here is my HTML code for the navigation menu.

```
  <div class="sidenav">
    <a class="current3" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="https://robertevansuni.uk/Journal/">Journal</a>
    <button class="dropdown-btn">Davids Work
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>  
    <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a class="dropdowntext2" href="three-designed-objects-homepage.html">Designed Objects</a>
<!--
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
-->
</div>

  <button class="dropdown-btn">Priscas Work
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a class="dropdowntext2" href="Typography-arrangement.html">Typography</a>
    <a class="dropdowntext2" href="lithome.html">Literature</a>
<!--     <a href="#">Link 3</a> -->

  </div>
  <a class="submenu"href="oldwebsites.html">Archived Websites</a>
  <a class="nav-menu" href="about.html">About</a>
  <button class="openBtn" onclick="openSearch()">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to use javascript to get more of this functionality you want to do where you get the `window.location.href` to get the current page and adding the ' already open ' dropdown class to that button/link if the button and page are both respected to each other

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on that? sorry.

Comment: Are you using JQuery ?

Comment: I've just downloaded it and refferanced it in my HTML.